# How to assemble a multi-project ant build system

Tags: ant, build, dependencies, ivy, multi-project

At my new gig, they use Ant and cannot be persuaded to move to Maven. 
I've looked everywhere for a decent example of how a multi-project ant build system should be assembled. The apache site falls short. I'm looking specifically for best practices to:

- Automatically build local projects that are dependencies of a project
- Share artifacts from project to their dependents
- Export a project's dependencies and generated artifacts (jars) to be inherited by dependent projects
- Share third-party dependencies between projects

I'm sure I can do all this without using Ivy - what did people do before Ivy? I really don't want to have to set up a corporate repository or rely on external repositories - the engineers here are really against that and have all their third-party jars checked into src control.

Can anyone point me at a good open source example of a multi-project ant build?

Comment: Sorry to say that but reinventing the maven reactor, the concept of local/remote repositories, dependencies management and the conventions that come with it when you already have all this in Maven sounds insane.

Comment: I'm not trying to re-invent it. It's not an option. I certainly don't want to use remote or local repositories. I just want to know what the best practices are/were before Maven or Ivy. I fully appreciate why those tools were invented now I'm dealing with this mess! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have too much hands on experience with building large numbers of dependent projects with Ant, but [this tutorial](http://www.exubero.com/ant/dependencies.html) looks like it will do what you need without any additional tools.

Comment: Thanks! My searching efforts somehow missed this article - it looks pretty good so far.